# How to track the SQL calls from eclipse-link JPA to DB

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am using eclipse link as a JPA implementation and am connected to a DB running on "`jdbc:XXX://localhost:35001/`".  Is there a way I can track all the sql calls?  I am running this inside a java project in eclipse on my local machine.

Thanks

Comment: Use a proxy driver like P6spy

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "track"? Different interpretations are possible on this term here.

Answer (score 1):

Several options you can try:

You could try using a proxy like P6spy as mentioned by Andreas, or alternative ones like [log4jdbc](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc) etc. This can be useful in debugging when you are trying to trace calls from multiple clients since the proxy could intercept the calls from them all.

However for your case I would suggest using the built in logging facilities of EclipseLink. In eclipse link you can configure logging of the statements via entries in the persistence XML like shown below:

```
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

I would suggest that after making the code changes to undeploy the application and stop and restart the application server before rebuilding and then deploying the application again. I have seen more than few instances where the logging does not start with you going through this entire cycle.

The last option would be a SQL trace. Depending on your database backend you might be able to run a profile or trace. SQL-Server would allow you to trace it. You can then view all SQL executed against the database. This is probably overkill in your scenario as it will log all activity unless configured incorrectly.